# Eclipse Ant task p2.composite.repository not honoring append=false

Tags: eclipse, p2

I'm using the docs at

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_repositorytasks.htm

I'm trying to setup a build file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project name="osgi.composite.p2">
  <target name="osgi.composite.p2">
    <p2.composite.repository>
      <repository append="false" location="/d01/osgi/DS_5000_10_0_0" name="DS_5000_10_0_0 Composite"/>
      <add>
        <repository location="DS_5000_10_0_0.HEAD.1308021100.8500"/>
        <repository location="thirdparty"/>
        <repository location="e4"/>
        <repository location="../nebula/"/>
        <repository location="../integration/FUSION_DS_5000_8_3_0_SSO/"/>
      </add>
    </p2.composite.repository>
  </target>
</project>
```

to overwrite the P2 composite index by running

```
/d01/sandboxes/baron/eclipse/4.3/eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile composite.p2-8500.xml osgi.composite.p2
```

And instead of creating a new composite index it's appending the new entries listed in the build file to the compositeContent.jar, but properly replacing the entries in the compositeArtifacts.jar.

Comment: I run into the same issue. As a workaround I delete `compositeArtifacts.jar` and `compositeContent.jar`  before invoking `<p2.composite.repository>` and start from scratch.